# Android Limiting signup for one user

Tags: java, android, sqlite, limit

I developed an android application ... It is an applications first page... two buttons it have ... signup and sign in .. when user enter for first time he needs to signup and when sign up is pressed registration process will start ... user has to give an username, password and a mobile number .. once he give all this a passcode will be generated annd will be send to the mobile number provided user has to enter this passcode recieved along with the username and password to register... once he got register .. he can signin with the username and password.
Al these part is working fine ... My requirement is to limit the registration for only 1 username.... so for one download one username is allowed .. after one registartion the signup option must deactivated... so what I have to do for that .. I am giving the code ..below...

MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


     Button btnSignIn,btnSignUp;
    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();


        btnSignIn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);
        btnSignUp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUP);



        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intentSignUP=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUPActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentSignUP);

            }
        });
    }

    public void signIn(View V)
    {
         final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
         dialog.setTitle("Login");

         // get the References of views
         final  EditText editTextUserName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
         final  EditText editTextPassword=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);
         final  EditText editTextMobileNumber = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText1);


         Button btnSignIn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);


         btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                String mobileNumber = editTextMobileNumber.getText().toString();

                // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
                String storedPassword=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);



                String sd = getIntent().getStringExtra("number"); 




                // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
                if(password.equals(storedPassword) && (mobileNumber.equals(sd))) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });


         dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Close The Database
        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
}
}
```

Signup Activity

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SignUPActivity extends Activity

{
    EditText editTextUserName,editTextPassword,editTextConfirmPassword, editMobileNumber;
    Button btnCreateAccount;


    Random r = new Random();
    int number =r.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;



    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);

        // get Instance  of Database Adapter
        loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

        // Get References of Views


        editTextUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextConfirmPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);
        editMobileNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobileNumber);




        btnCreateAccount=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount);
        btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
            String confirmPassword=editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString();

            String phoneNo = editMobileNumber.getText().toString();
            String sms = Integer.toString(number);


            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUPActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("number", sms + "");
            startActivity(intent);



            StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(phoneNo,",");
            while (st.hasMoreElements())

            {

                String tempMobileNumber = (String)st.nextElement();
                if(tempMobileNumber.length()>0 && sms.trim().length()>0) {
                    sendSMS(tempMobileNumber, sms);

                }


                else 

                {

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                            "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }








            // check if any of the fields are vacant
            if(userName.equals("")||password.equals("")||confirmPassword.equals(""))
            {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
            }
            // check if both password matches
            if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                // Save the Data in Database
                loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(userName, password);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created and the passcode is sent to the mobile number you provided. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();






            }
        }
    });
}










    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

      //---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        },new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                        
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);       


    }









    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();

        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    }



}
```

LoginDataBaseAdapter.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class LoginDataBaseAdapter {

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login.db";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
    // TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
    // SQL Statement to create a new database.
    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"LOGIN"+
                                 "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD text); ";
    // Variable to hold the database instance
    public  SQLiteDatabase db;
    // Context of the application using the database.
    private final Context context;
    // Database open/upgrade helper
    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
    public  LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) 
    {
        context = _context;
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public  LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close() 
    {
        db.close();
    }

    public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
    {
        return db;
    }

    public void insertEntry(String userName,String password)
    {
       ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        // Assign values for each row.
        newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
        newValues.put("PASSWORD",password);

        // Insert the row into your table
        db.insert("LOGIN", null, newValues);
        ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public int deleteEntry(String UserName)
    {
        //String id=String.valueOf(ID);
        String where="USERNAME=?";
        int numberOFEntriesDeleted= db.delete("LOGIN", where, new String[]{UserName}) ;
       // Toast.makeText(context, "Number for Entry Deleted Successfully : "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
    }    
    public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName)
    {
        Cursor cursor=db.query("LOGIN", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
        cursor.close();
        return password;                
    }
    public void  updateEntry(String userName,String password)
    {
        // Define the updated row content.
        ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
        // Assign values for each row.
        updatedValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
        updatedValues.put("PASSWORD",password);

        String where="USERNAME = ?";
        db.update("LOGIN",updatedValues, where, new String[]{userName});               
    }        

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it simple

Just get the count of the **LOGIN** Table. If it returns 1 then hide the `SignUp` button otherwise show the `SignUP` button. Use the following line of code to get the total count of the table.

**In Activity**

```
 if(loginDataBaseAdapter.getUsercount()==1){
          btnSignUp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 }
```

**In Database**

```
   public long getUsercount() { 
        return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "LOGIN");
    }
```

It should work.

Comment: Hi roshanpeter just remove that line it should work.

Comment: without removing it ,,,,it worked....thanks and I accepted u r answer.... I will post the code here...

Comment: public long getUsercount() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "LOGIN");
    } 
    
    
    
    private SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
  return db;
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }

Comment: yes you can do both way.. Because you intitialized the db before itself son no problems either removing it or not.you welcome.. Happy coding

Comment: Hello .. Vino this is working fine as .. after 1 registration signup button is invisible..can u pls tell what change we need to provide for making limit to 2 or 3 .. igave like if(loginDataBaseAdapter.getUsercount()==2){
          btnSignUp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 }    but it is not working

Comment: if(loginDataBaseAdapter.getUsercount()>=2)

Answer (score 1):

A quick simple approach would be to use a "marker" that carries a value indicating if they created an account or not. You can use a boolean or an int.

So your programming logic would go as such:

Main Activity

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


 Button btnSignIn,btnSignUp;
LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
    loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();


    btnSignIn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);
    btnSignUp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUP);



    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(getValue("registrationComplete"==1){
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You already have registered.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
           else{
                Intent intentSignUP = new
            Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUPActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentSignUP);
                  }
        }
    });
}

public void signIn(View V)
{
     final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
     dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
     dialog.setTitle("Login");

     // get the References of views
     final  EditText editTextUserName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
     final  EditText editTextPassword=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);
     final  EditText editTextMobileNumber = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText1);


     Button btnSignIn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);


     btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
            String mobileNumber = editTextMobileNumber.getText().toString();

            // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
            String storedPassword=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);



            String sd = getIntent().getStringExtra("number"); 




            // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
            if(password.equals(storedPassword) && (mobileNumber.equals(sd))) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });


     dialog.show();
}
public int getValue(String name) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    return prefs.getInt(name, 0);
    }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Close The Database
    loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    }
}
```

SingUp Activity

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SignUPActivity extends Activity
{
EditText editTextUserName,editTextPassword,editTextConfirmPassword, editMobileNumber;
Button btnCreateAccount;


Random r = new Random();
int number =r.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;



LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signup);

    // get Instance  of Database Adapter
    loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
    loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

    // Get References of Views


    editTextUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
    editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    editTextConfirmPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);
    editMobileNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobileNumber);




    btnCreateAccount=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount);
    btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
        String confirmPassword=editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString();

        String phoneNo = editMobileNumber.getText().toString();
        String sms = Integer.toString(number);


        Intent intent = new Intent(SignUPActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("number", sms + "");
        startActivity(intent);



        StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(phoneNo,",");
        while (st.hasMoreElements())

        {

            String tempMobileNumber = (String)st.nextElement();
            if(tempMobileNumber.length()>0 && sms.trim().length()>0) {
                sendSMS(tempMobileNumber, sms);

            }


            else 

            {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }








        // check if any of the fields are vacant
        if(userName.equals("")||password.equals("")||confirmPassword.equals(""))
        {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
        }
        // check if both password matches
        if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // Save the Data in Database
            loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(userName, password);
            // Set value of registrationComplete to 1 to indicate its done.
            setValue("registrationComplete",1);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created and the passcode is sent to the mobile number you provided. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();






        }
    }
});
}

public void setValue(String name, int newValue) {
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt(name, newValue);
editor.commit();
}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

  //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    },new IntentFilter(SENT));

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;                        
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);       


}









@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
}
```

Comment: thanks Challenge Accepted... can you pls tell me where I have to add this code in my codee........

Comment: thanks.. ChallengeAccpted.. I am just working with the code .. after, I will accept u r answer....

Comment: @roshanpeter Sure thing. Its always a pleasure to help a fellow android programmer. Let me know how it works out for you or if you want additional help with it. I also cleaned up my answer and formatted it to be more easier to followup on now.

Comment: thanks Challenge..... sure needed help ... can u pls tell where I hav to add this code is it in MainActivity ... inisde the btnSignup click activity

Comment: Once I start something, I have to complete it. Anyways I'm all done. Check the answer for the updates. Hope that solves everything else.

Comment: Oh.. thanks... Challenhge. .. I accepted u r answer ... pls help me if any help needed 4 me... thanks..

Comment: @roshanpeter Its very late and I will be going to sleep. Let me know if you were able to solve the problem :)

Comment: @roshanpeter Check my answer now. I included the code within your two activities that needed editing. Should work.

Comment: Yes add that. it should be if(getValue("registrationComplete"==1)){

Comment: where the open bracket is closing

Comment: It is saying that incompatible operand string and int

Comment: I'm very sorry its 2am and I can't think straight. It should be (getValue("registrationComplete")==1){

Comment: I liked vinos solution as well but for now if mines is easier for you and it works then use my solution.goodnight and glad to have it working!